# Module 'xml.dom' has no attribute 'Node'

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, attributeerror, minidom

I wanted to use the module xml in Python 3.7, however i am getting the following error :

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from xml.dom import minidom
  File "C:\Users\EMurairi18\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 30, in <module>
    _nodeTypes_with_children = (xml.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE,
AttributeError: module 'xml.dom' has no attribute 'Node'
>>>
```

What is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to replicate the error installing python3.7.0, but it's all working fine. Maybe there were conflicting packages in that installation (which could be prevented by managing dependencies within a python virtual environment, or any similar option), or maybe the issue is fixed if there was any.